# Is there a way to render a view only once in ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Currently, this is how I have my view set up on my server.js when the root page is accessed:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('home.jade');
});
```

And in home.jade,

```
include head
include top
include left
body
    div.container
        p   Welcome to the homepage.
```

This works fine, but the problem is that when a different page is accessed, I will have to include head.jade, top.jade, and left.jade each time. Is there a way to simply include them only *once*, and have only the body part changed each time I go to a different page? I took a look at partials, but it seems like that option was removed in Express 3.0+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render the head, top and left by:

```
res.render('static.jade', {}, function(err, html){
  // ...
});
```

When you specify the callback, then no response is sent and the result is in `html` var. Then you can do the same with 'home.jade', concatenate the two result strings and respond with

```
res.send(concatencated_html);
```

Please keep in mind that rendering the header will produce a full html output (`<html>...</html>`), that you need to trim before appending the rest to it (the same with beginning of second render).

For me it's just a lot simpler to keep includes in view files.

Comment: I don't think I explained the problem properly. This basically gives the same result as I have it now, and it doesn't solve the problem. When different pages are accessed, the head, top, and left still need to be rendered again. I am trying to find a way to render them only once - when a user clicks on a different link on the site, only the content/body section is changed, and the other parts(head, top, and left) are not re-loaded.

Comment: You can always render the head, top and left into some variable at the app start, and then just add it to other, dynamic renders. In this way you process these parts only once. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: If for an example, I put an animated image(infinite loop) on any of the top/head/left, the image will be reloaded back to its default position when I access another page.

Comment: Oh I understand now! It's not a problem of your server then. You have to rebuild your page to load only once, and then just load everything else with AJAX requests. It's the only way you can change content without reloading whole page. Just create some paths on the server which are used only for rendering the changing parts, and open them with client-side JS, and change the page content :)